# How to get the owner of the item?

Tags: jquery

I have simple HTML:

```
<div id="my1">
    <input id="my2" value="123">
</div>
```

Get the item my2:

```
item = $("#my2");
```

How to get the owner of the item?

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: You need this ??? http://jsfiddle.net/p910ys24/

Comment: There is no such thing as an "owner" in the DOM.  Do you mean the parent?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for parent div. you need to use **[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)** selector.

> Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
var my1= $("#my2").parent();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
var item = $("#my2");
var parentItem = item.parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use : `$( "#my2" ).closest( "div" )` as well as `$("#my2").parent()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
var my1 = $('#my2').parent();
```

Or

```
var my1= $("#my2").parents();
```

The `.parents()` and `.parent()` methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree. Also, `$( "html" ).parent()` method returns a set containing document whereas `$( "html" ).parents()` returns an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the parent for item.

```
var item = $("#my2");
console.log(item.parent());
```

This gives you the complete DOM information (details) about the element's parent.

```
console.log($("#my2").parent().prop('id'));
```

This gives you the specific property of the element.